# Assigned values but never used on React form

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My sign up form component is showing me warnings in the console saying my value are never used.

> Line 57:  'displayName' is assigned a value but never used      no-unused-vars
>
> Line 57:  'email' is assigned a value but never used            no-unused-vars
>
> Line 57:  'password' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
>
> Line 57:  'confirmPassword' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Here is some of the code I believe to be the problem.

```
            this.setState({
                displayName: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                confirmPassword: '',
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
 }
      handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }
    render(){
        const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state
        return(
            <div className='SignUpForm'>
            <h2 className='signupTitle'>New here? Sign up for an account.</h2>
            <form className='Signin' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">

            <TextField
              className='displayName'
              name='displayName'
              id="standard-name"
              type='text'
              label="Display Name"
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.displayName}
              required
            />

            <TextField
              className='email'
              name='email'
              id="standard-name"
              type='text'
              label="Email"
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.email}
              required
            />

              <TextField
             className='password'
             name='password'
             type='password'
             id="standard-password-input"
            label="Password"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.password}
            required
            />

              <TextField
             className='confirmPassword'
             name='confirmPassword'
             type='password'
             id="standard-password-input"
            label="Confirm Password"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.confirmPassword}
            required
            />
```

The sign up form works correctly and a new user is added to Firebase database.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you declare your `state: { }`?

Comment: At the top of your `render` function, you're creating local variables for displayName, email, password, and confirmPassword by destructuring state. In your components, you're passing `this.state.{variable}` for each of these variables, so the locals you declare are never used, as your warnings point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causing the warning,

```
const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state
```

Here you are getting your state into separate variables but you are not using them anywhere in your code.

You have two ways,

1. Either remove this line.
2. Or You can use them like,

```
<TextField
  className='displayName'
  name='displayName'
  id="standard-name"
  type='text'
  label="Display Name"
  margin="normal"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  value={displayName}   //Instead of this.state.displayName use displayName only
  required
/>
```

Like this you can use other variables in other appropriate `TextField`.

Comment: Ok that did it, I understand now. Thanks.